# will_paginate with 2 list on the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I have too list @comments and @eval in the same view. If I go to the page 2 in the @eval, the comments page go to the page 2 as well, there is a simple way to do this in the separated way?

Comment: You can implement pagination via AJAX

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom parameter name (`param_name`) for each pagination link group and differentiate the page number by that:

```
# in view
<%= will_paginate @foos, :param_name => :foo_page %>
<%= will_paginate @bars, :param_name => :bar_page %> 

# in controller
@foo = Foo.paginate(page: params[:foo_page])
@bar = Bar.paginate(page: params[:bar_page])
```

Find the list of possible options in the source code of the gem: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/v3.0.5/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb#L46